# How can I programmatically construct a pack: URI to refer to a resource in a different assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to programmatically construct a pack: `Uri`. This fails:

```
Uri myuri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/lookup2.xml");
```

It seems like maybe this was supported in some environments (based on other answers I've seen) but it throws `System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: Invalid port specified` for me.

This works:

```
Uri appBase = new Uri("application:///", UriKind.Absolute);
Uri appPath = new Uri("/lookup2.xml", UriKind.Relative);
Uri packUri = PackUriHelper.Create(appBase, appPath)
```

That returns the pack: URI for a resource in the current assembly. Now I want to create `pack://application:,,,/OtherAssembly;component/lookup2.xml`.

And I cannot work out how to do that. Perhaps I'm overlooking something obvious. But if I make the `/OtherAssembly;component/` part of the `appPath`, the "/" characters gets escaped. I get `pack://application:,,,,OtherAssembly;component/lookup2.xml` which isn't right as far as I can tell from the MS docs about assembly references in pack: URIs.

It looks like maybe a `PackagePart` would help, but I'm not sure. I can't see how to construct one from an `Assembly` anyway.

Pointers, please?

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection, I wonder if there's a bug in the MS documentation. It claims that the path must conform to `AssemblyShortName{;Version]{;PublicKey];component/Path` and then goes on to show examples that have a leading "/" before the "AssemblyShortName" which isn't consistent with the description, but which is achievable with the PackUriHelper.

Comment: On the other hand, Microsoft's `BaseUriHelper` class does seem to add the slash: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/323a02eccd0353a9d2a5e7efd3b6177e9a1e1097/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationCore/System/Windows/Navigation/BaseUriHelper.cs#L505

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer below. First `Uri` output is fine. The second one gets jumbled up because I think `PackUriHelper` may not be able to handle this scenario. Perhaps will help.

```
            Uri appBase = new Uri("application:///", UriKind.Absolute);
            Uri appAssembly = new Uri("/OtherAssembly;component", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            Uri appBaseOtherAssembly = PackUriHelper.Create(appBase, appAssembly);
            Console.WriteLine(appBaseOtherAssembly.ToString()); //pack://application:,,,/OtherAssembly;component
            Uri appPath = new Uri("/lookup2.xml", UriKind.Relative);
            Uri completeUri = new Uri(appBaseOtherAssembly, appPath); 
            Console.WriteLine(completeUri.ToString());//not sure why; produces: pack://application:,,,/lookup2.xml 
            var uri = PackUriHelper.Create(appBaseOtherAssembly, appPath);
            Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString()); //pack://pack:,,application:%2C%2C%2C,OtherAssembly;component/lookup2.xml
```

Comment: But that results in a URI that doesn't resemble the documented pack: URIs at all, either the ones defined in the MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 or the ones defined in the ID: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-shur-pack-uri-scheme-05

Comment: Edited. Could not get the complete one but perhaps little useful.

Comment: Thanks for trying! I don't think `pack://pack:,, ...` is going to work either though.